# Standard math latex font

Tags: math-mode, fonts

What is the standard font in latex math?
Is possible to describe this in terms of serif and arial/times etc.?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Modern for some background.

Comment: I think the best *typographical* description is probably in Knuth's books, but you might start with [the WP page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Modern).

Answer (score 3):

Standard `LaTeX` font is `CMR` (Computer Modern Roman) font families, and you can get the font families in `Times` by using:

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

And for both the `Times` and `Arial` font, try with `.otf` font in `XeLaTeX` which supports `.otf` fonts in an easier way....